# How to limit traffic on linux VM to certain IP range?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to Linux and have a VM up and running for a Rails application. I want to limit traffic to the site so only the people within my organization can access the site. If I have the range how do I se this up in Ubuntu to limit traffic?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Apache.

EDIT: Here is the conf file for the site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
PassengerRuby /home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby
ServerName site.com
ServerAlias alias.com
ServerAdmin username
DocumentRoot /home/username/rails/site/public/
RailsEnv development
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/home/username/rails/site/public/">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>

<LocationMatch "server.com">
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from xxx.xxx.0.0/16
</LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apache LocationMatch Directive.  Put the Directive within the Virtual Host specification. For example:

`<LocationMatch "/your/specific/url">
      order deny,allow
      deny from all
      allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
</LocationMatch>`

Comment: Thank you. What file would this go in do you know?

Comment: I found it but it doesn't seem to be working still. I ave updated my original post and added the virtual hosts section. Is there anything else in there that would affect this? I have also restarted the apache service as well as the VM.